# call to finish() causes startActivity() AndroidRuntimeException

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

Sometimes, when I close a particular activity with the finish() method, I get the error:

`AndroidRuntimeException “Calling startActivity() from outside of an Activity context requires the FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK flag”`

This seems to only happen if I close the activity (by clicking a back button) quickly after it is started.  It doesn't happen all of the time however.  Here's the activity hierarchy in a nutshell:

MainActivity->ListViewActivity->ItemViewActivity

The error occurs (periodically) when returning from ItemView.

To describe the full chain, I have a button in MainActivity, when pressed it calls listCLick

```
  public void listClick(View view) {
    Intent myIntent = new Intent(this, ListViewActivity.class);
    startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);        
  }
```

Then, when an item in the list view is clicked, it calls the overwritten onItemClick method

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
    Intent itemintent = new Intent(this, ItemViewActivity.class);
    startActivity(itemintent);
}
```

I am using a TextView (with an image and text) in the ItemViewActivity that the user can click on to return to the previous activity.

```
    TextView tempView;
    // close this activity if someone clicks the waypoint's icon.
    tempView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview);
    tempView.setText("Back");
    tempView.setOnClickListener(backListener);
```

where backListener is defined as:

```
private OnClickListener backListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        finish();
    }
};
```

So I never get the error when actually calling startActivity() myself, only when I am returning from an activity.  Here's the stack trace:

```
Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: Calling startActivity() from outside of an Activity  context requires the FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK flag. Is this really what you want?
at android.app.ApplicationContext.startActivity(ApplicationContext.java:550)
at android.content.ContextWrapper.startActivity(ContextWrapper.java:248)
at android.webkit.CallbackProxy.uiOverrideUrlLoading(CallbackProxy.java:205)
at android.webkit.CallbackProxy.handleMessage(CallbackProxy.java:304)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4363)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `startActivityForResult()` is not designed to start activities that, in turn, start yet other activities. `startActivityForResult()` is designed for starting an activity that, from a flow standpoint, behaves like a dialog: user picks something, and control returns to the original activity. I **strongly** encourage you to avoid using `startActivityForResult()` in the manner that you are.

Comment: CommonsWare, is there a better way to return a result from an Activity?

Comment: In this case, I would recommend eliminating the need to "return a result from an Activity". `MainActivity` should be able to stand alone, not caring what happens in `ListViewActivity`, since `ListViewActivity` itself lets the user go much deeper within your app.

Answer (score 0):

Add the Override method `onDestroy();` to your activity that had the problem that stated above and within it call `super.onDestroy();` method, in this case when you press the back button to the activity that you just started it, it will be finished with maintaining its Life Cycle,  just do as below:

```
@Override 
public void onDestroy(){
super.onDestroy();
}
```

Hope this help